# Creating a list of objects with a class in Python

Tags: python, list, class, object

I am trying to emulate a Java toString method I learned a while back.  I might be off base here and there may definitely be an easier way to do what I'm trying to do with a simple list.

What I really want to do is be able to append objects to a list, and then print specific traits about those objects from the list.  I also want to keep track of the index of the object.  Here is what I have so far, but when I print, I get no errors, and a blank line, nothing prints.

```
class Character_list():
    def __init__(self, list):
        self.list = []

def toString(self):
    result = ""
    for i in self.list:
        result += self.list[i]

    return result

def main(): 
    x = Character_list([1, 2])
    print(x.toString())

main()
```

Comment: As `self.list = []`, there's nothing to be printed... You probably meant `self.list = list`.

Comment: Not sure what the intention is. Python classes already have a `__str__` method that you can write for yourself to customise how the objects are displayed when a string representation is needed.

Comment: You shouldn't use `list` as a variable name as it clashes with the `list()` inbuilt function in Python. Change it to something else like `char_list` etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three things:

First, use the parameter you pass to the constructor to *actually* instantiate your object

```
class Character_list():
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst  # use the parameter! And don't use 'list' as a variable name
        # or even better, use a shallow copy:
        self.lst = list(lst)
```

Second, python loops are generally *for-each* loops. That means you are iterating elements, not indexes. So

```
    for i in self.lst:
        result += i
```

will actually append the list elements (which have to be strings, otherwise use: `result += str(i)`) to `result`.

Third, Python's version of `toString` is `__str__` and is implicitly called when using the the built-in `str()` on an object. So, for instance

```
def __str__(self):
    return ''.join(map(str, self.lst))
```

will do what you intended, but more generally, e.g. when you call

```
print(x)
```